# Python | Как работает данная функция?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
result = 0
def sum_of_digits(number):
    return sum(int(d) for d in str(number))
print(sum_of_digits(15))
```

Данная программа суммирует все цифры числа. Но я не могу понять, что делает данная строка кода:

```py
return sum(int(d) for d in str(number))
```

Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разложите `sum(int(d) for d in str(number))` по частям:

1. `sum(... for ... in ...)` -- выражение внутри скобок создаст генератор, который вернет значения из цикла. Можно создать и список, для этого используются квадратные скобки: `sum([... for ... in ...])`, но это не эффективно в данном случае.
2. `str(number)` -- вернет строку из числа. Передали число `123`, получили строку `"123"`. Приводим к строке, т.к. это самый простой способ получить из числа его цифры
3. `for d in ...` -- будет перебирать символы из строки, т.е. сначала `"1"`, потом `"2"`, и т.д.
4. `int(d)` -- сконвертирует строку в число (в десятичной системе), это нужно из-за того, что `sum` не умеет работать со строками.
5. `sum(...)` -- принимает и суммирует, то, что можно итерировать (списки, кортежи, генераторы, и т.п.)

Если, `number = 123`, то `sum(int(d) for d in str(number))`, образно, станет `sum((1, 2, 3))`, что равно `6`

---

**PS.**

Выражение `sum(int(d) for d in str(number))` можно представить в функциональном виде: `sum(map(int, str(number)))`

Answer (score 1):

Создаётся генераторное выражение, переданное число преобразовывается в строковый тип `str(number)`, для того что бы пройтись циклом по каждому отдельному символу (для 15 это - 1 и 5), попутно преобразовывая их обратно в целочисленный тип `int(d)`. За тем, применяется функция суммирования `sum()` и возвращается результат.
В вашем случае, передав на вход функции число 15, мы получим 6=(1+5).